# Redirecting and then moving target file

Tags: bash, unix, stdout, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I tested the following on AIX and it works.

```
logfile=log.txt
echo "Hello" > "$logfile"
exec 1>>"$logfile"
mv "$logfile" "${logfile}_new"
echo "World"
```

After this script ran the file `log.txt_new` will contain:

```
Hello
World
```

I was not expecting it to work because I renamed the file to where `stdout` was being redirected. Why does it work?

It also works if I mv/rename the directory that contains the log file.

Answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/how-do-open-files-behave-on-linux-systems

Comment: `exec 1>>"$logfile"` Here you are redirecting the command output right?  From bash manual-   If no command is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment.

Comment: I am not sure why it is redirecting to new file instead of stdout

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes from the command `mv`.

In this case, `mv` does not really `move` the file, but just give it a new name.

The content of the file stays unchanged, and it's still the destination of the standard output of your current shell.

That's why the `echo` command still outputs into the original file.